# Can we stop googlebot crawling old pdf url

Tags: seo

In my site their is a button linking to PDF. Let say current pdf url on button is http://www.abc.come/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/xyz.pdf and this url google bot has crawled. Now later after month from admin, administrator uploads new pdf let say http://www.abc.come/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/xyz-latest.pdf and updates url on button.

Issue is that googlebot is still crawling old url with xyz.pdf  and giving 404 in webmaster tools.

How can we make googlebot to stop crawling old url and crawl new ones.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a redirect? Also not programming related.

Comment: a 404 is the correct response for deleted urls, there is no need to change that. Google needs to crawl the url to get the 404 and understand it has been deleted. The 404 report in webmaster tools is just to let you know what was found (or not) on your site. 404's do not harm your site

Answer (score -1):

Yup you can.

Under webmaster go to Google Index -> Remove URLS. Remove you url from here and then from your app. Works for me.

Comment: This is not a correct use of the removal tool. There is no need to use the removal tool in the search console for urls that have been deleted. There is nothing to remove, google has already crawled and seen the 404.

Comment: you can stop it to recrawl the pages and eventually after several crawls it gets removed from the SERP. That is how it works from what I understand

Comment: No, urls removed by the removal tool can still be crawled. They arent actually removed, they are just hidden in search results. Read more here https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/05/do-404s-hurt-my-site.html  and also see the last question on that page > Q: Can I use Google’s URL removal tool to make 404 errors disappear from my account faster?
A: No; the URL removal tool removes URLs from Google’s search results, not from your Webmaster Tools account.

Comment: No; the URL removal tool removes URLs from Google’s search results, not from your Webmaster Tools account 1, you are contradicting urself :/

Comment: No I am not. Why do you say that ?

Comment: This is more up to date for you and makes it more clear the function of removal tool is to hide from serps > 

Temporarily hide page ..  Google will recrawl the page during the blackout period and refresh the page cache and snippet, but will not show them until the blackout period expires
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en

-- You can test this yourself - remove a page and watch your logs, google will still crawl it just fine.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, my solution was an entry in the .htaccess with an 410 ('gone') statuscode. After some time google stops crawling. 
But I also read that Google will stop crawling when 404. But on my site it keeps crawling 404-sites.

Comment: If that means you changed the 404 to a redirect to a 410, then you would have made a redirect 301/302 instead of a 4xx. Which wouldnt be right.

Comment: No that means that Apache sends a 410 header instead of 404. So Google knows the file was actually there but now it's gone.

Comment: not if you redirected it, as you said "a redirect in .htaccess"